# In Facebook Comments, how to disable the mobile ver of it? And, what decide if a device is mobile or not?

Tags: html, facebook, mobile, responsive-design, facebook-comments

I'm now designing Facebook Comments for my personal Wordpress. But I got stuck for the setting on mobile version of it.

[image: Desktop version of Facebook Comments]
*Desktop version of Facebook Comments*
[image: Mobile version of Facebook Comments]
*Mobile version of Facebook Comments*

According to the [Docs of Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#settings), the setting `mobile` is set to be `"auto-detect"` by default. Since the mobile Facebook Comments lacks good design, I'd like to make it the same as the desktop version. Then I set the attribute `mobile` to `false`, but this didn't work when I opened the site in mobile device. It's still the mobile ver of it. [A temp demo is here](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#comments)

So now, how to make Facebook Comments *always the desktop version*?

Also, how does it decide whether the device is mobile? I can also pretend the browser to be mobile in dev tools. Just pretty curious about this.

UPDATE:

@björn-kaiser, the following is my HTML code for Facebook Comments. Too bad it did not work still. [Temp demo as before](http://chenghuayang.com/blog/love-lorem-ipsum/#comments)

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="false" data-width="100%" data-numposts="3" data-href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" mobile="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is actually called `data-mobile` not `mobile`. I just tried it and it seems to work. Setting it to `false` rendered the "desktop" version and setting it to true forced it to be the mobile one.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-mobile="false" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Comment: I set up this but not working thought. See my updates above please.

Comment: Hm, for me it renders the proper version, even on your page it renders the nicely styled one. In case that matters, I opened it on an iPhone 5s with iOS 9

Comment: So did you see just like [this](http://i.imgur.com/nwvwkHC.jpg)? (On iPhone 6 / iOS 9 / Chrome)